"Start in" windows 10 NO SHORTCUT
How do I edit the "start in" box of file explorer properties. It is grayed out for me. I cannot seem to find any answer to this.

Is it possibly becuase I lack "special permissions" whatever that means? How do I give myself that.

I found this post, but everyone was saying "just make a shortcut" which I do not wish to do. Set default/starting folder for Explorer in taskbar without duplicate icon on launch in Windows 8.1

Just create shortcut to something that is not,...system thing, thats only reason you think you have the issue, the thing works as intended. Windows knows where its Desktop is, you cant open "Desktop" in "C:\Windows" for example.

This isn't about permissions. This is an Advertised Shortcut. Maybe COM shell objects could achieve the desired effect, but I'm not sure.

No; It has nothing with Special Permissions. Why are you unwilling to implement the solution to your problem?

Apparently it is possible to change it, but only if what you want to change it to is "This PC" (becuase that and quick access seem to be the only options), which luckily just so happened to be what I wanted to do. If you want to change it to some other folder, it seems that the aforementioned shortcut method is the only way.
But, to change it to "This PC", simply open file explorer, go to the view tab, and click options. There should be a "start in" option. More into here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-file-explorer-to-open-to-this-pc-instead-of-quick-access-b2c7d271-027b-b35f-917e-897f66e68e5c#WindowsVersion=Windows_10

Create the shortcut to Windows Explorer manually to set the location where it opens, as shown below. Do not use Start in:, though, because it has no effect. Instead, set the location where Explorer opens using a command line argument.


Right-click the Desktop.

Select New > Shortcut.

Enter explorer.exe in the location box.

Rename the shortcut as you wish.

Right-click the new shortcut.

Select Properties.

In the Target: box, add a space and the path to where Explorer should open.
In this example, \temp makes Explorer open to C:\temp.



Is a hacky shortcut method truly the only way? Why can I not just edit the "start in" box

That is the way Windows works -- Explorer is built into the OS. There are third-party Explorer replacements, and those might allow editing the "Start in;" box.
